# removing the first and the last character of every line from command line

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I am trying to remove the first and the last characters of everyline in a text file and save the resulting truncated version in a new file. Does anyone have an idea about how to do that efficiently using `awk` or other linux programs/commands specifically for large files?

#### input.txt

```
(s,2,4,5,6)
"s,1,5,5,2"
{z,0,4,5,3}
[y,2,4,5,5]
(y,4,4,5,7)
(r,20,4,5,7)
(e,9,4,5,2)
```

#### Expected output.txt

```
s,2,4,5,6
s,1,5,5,2
z,0,4,5,3
y,2,4,5,5
y,4,4,5,79
r,20,4,5,7
e,9,4,5,2
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Another way just for the heck of it:

```
rev input | cut -c2- | rev | cut -c2-
```

<sub>(Note: with GNU `cut`, it only works for characters made of only one byte (as in your example)).</sub>

Comment: Nice! This is significantly faster than the sed and awk solutions proposed so far.

Comment: I proposed this answer for people afraid of sed/awk/regex syntax, but wouldn't have imagined it's faster, especially for large files, with three pipes and passing the entire contents through each one. Would have thought sed or awk reading a line at a time would be more efficient for large files.

Comment: Guess that's what 40+ years of optimization of many of these *nix utilities will get you!

Comment: @Gilles, it's faster to GNU sed in utf8 locales for some forms of input, and it depends whether you're considering wall clock time, or CPU time. `ssed` or the Heirloom toolchest `sed` can achieve better performance.

Comment: @Gilles Theres no MAN entry for rev in Solaris 5.10. I ended up using `sed`

Answer (score 14):

As per you question delete last and first word from input file as below :

```
sed 's/.$//; s/^.//' inputfile
```

Comment: It would be cool if you could benchmark these against the other solution, `s/.\(.*\).$/\1/`. It might be faster on account of not using backreferences, and the question did mention "large files".

Comment: @l0b0 I tested with `time yes | head -n 10000000 | COMMAND >/dev/null`. I get `rev input | cut -c2- | rev | cut -c2-` → 0.14s, `sed 's,.\(.*\).$,\1,'` → 3.38s; `awk '{print substr($0,2,length()-2);}'` → 3.50s; `sed 's/.$//; s/^.//'` → 5.09s.

Comment: @Gilles +1 That should be an answer.

Comment: @Gilles, that's very short lines. I find that for 30 character wide lines, @RahulPatil's solution is 3 times as fast with GNU sed than @juampa's. Also. `sed 's/.\(.*\)./\1/'` appears to be faster than `sed 's/^.\(.*\).$/\1/'` (GNU sed again). Also, the performance is dependant on the locale (interpretation of what a character is) and the `sed` implementation (in that regard, sed from the heirloom toolchest is considerably faster than GNU sed).

Answer (score 7):

There are many possibilities, as always

```
sed 's,.\(.*\).$,\1,g' your_file
```

#### Explanation

- `,` -- the sed delimiter, can be any other character as well, given it is escaped where-ever needed.
- `.` Match a single character
- `\(.*\)` - Group the remaining part, and this is stored to be retrieve further.
- `.` Match a single character again
- `$` - End of line
- `\1` - output the text matched by group above
- `g` replace globally on the line.

Comment: Why `g`? there will be only one match per line.

Comment: Note that it won't remove anything from lines that have fewer than 2 characters.

Answer (score 5):

```
tr -d '()[]{}"' < your_file
```

This should work as well. It well "translate" each of the characters to nothing (delete).

The downside is that it will delete them if they are not the first/last character as well. It will also miss any ending characters you don't list in the `()[...`.

Answer (score 4):

You can also do it with `awk` if you prefer

```
awk '{print substr($0,2,length()-2);}' input.txt > output.txt
```